# Timer/ScheduledExecutorService/Job scheduler not working properly

Tags: java, android

I need to call api for every 60 seconds without any time lag. But, I am getting seconds skip while using Timer,ScheduledExecutorService or Job scheduler when then device gets locked. I have tried all scenarios but can't able to fix this.

Comment: why not you try AlarmManager it will very useful for you

Comment: @yash786 since alarm manager is deprecated in recent api versions, i am not trying out alarm manager

Comment: What evidence do you have that AlarmManager is deprecated? The latest docs for  Android P:28 are here. [Alarm Manager Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager). There is no mention of deprecation.

Comment: For my scenario, i am using setInexactRepeating() and setRepeating() in alarm manager. But it limits due to battery optimization in recent OS versions.

Comment: While many of the APIs no longer work as the names advertise, AlarmManager is not (yet) deprecated. There is only 1 API that fires normally during doze: AlarmManager.setAlarmClock. Failing that, setExactAndAllowWhileIdle can be used if delays of up to ~10 minutes can be tolerated. Also, you might look at using a foreground service since they are mostly immune from doze within reason...

Comment: Thanks @Elletlar for your reply. But for the scenario what i am handling not getting the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same things by using Handler like below demo activity.

```
public class AnimationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler handler = new Handler();


    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            //Do your code here for API call
            handler.postDelayed(runnable,60000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation);

        handler.postDelayed(runnable,60000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(handler!=null && runnable!=null)
        {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Faldu Jaldeep, I have tried this solution but it is working for certain time after that the seconds/milliseconds gets skipped.